# Create file with tee and EOF in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

How to make this work inside a Dockerfile itself?

```
RUN tee /etc/yum.repos.d/docker-ce.repo<<EOF 
[docker-ce-stable] 
name=Docker CE Stable - \$basearch 
baseurl=https://download.docker.com/linux/fedora/38/\$basearch/stable 
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1 
gpgkey=https://download.docker.com/linux/fedora/gpg 
EOF
```

leads to:

```
#4 0.183 /bin/sh: line 1: warning: here-document at line 1 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
#4 0.207 /bin/sh: line 1: [docker-ce-stable]: command not found
```

Using `COPY ./docker-ce.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/docker-ce.repo` like suggested in the comments leads to this:

```
 => => # Warning: failed loading '/etc/yum.repos.d/docker-ce.repo', skipping.
#6 181.8 No match for argument: docker-ce
#6 182.1 No match for argument: docker-ce-cli
#6 182.4 No match for argument: containerd.io
#6 182.7 No match for argument: docker-buildx-plugin
#6 183.0 No match for argument: docker-compose-plugin
#6 183.2 Error: Unable to find a match: docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-buildx-plugin docker-compose-plugin
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c dnf install -y nodejs fuse-overlayfs docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-buildx-plugin docker-compose-plugin]: exit code: 1
```

Comment: What's going wrong?  Can you `COPY` a prebuilt file into the image, instead of trying to create it this way?

Comment: Like this `COPY ./docker-ce.repo /` ?

Comment: You have to remove the escaping of the variables if you copy the file -> `baseurl=https://download.docker.com/linux/fedora/38/$basearch/stable` and `name=Docker CE Stable - $basearch`

Comment: I can not verify since it is one year old, however this seems plausible.